# EditText.getText().toString() crashes on button click

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext

I have the following problem. I want to check my `EditText` if it contains a value/string on `Button` click. Here we go:

```
private EditText Name;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.RegisterName);

}

    public void RegisterClick(View v)
{
    String StrName = Name.getText().toString();
    if(StrName != "")
        Toast.makeText(null, "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And I put also this into the **layout.xml**, its not the whole code

```
<Button
android:onClick="RegisterClick" />
```

So now, when I try to debug, the debugger closes after I pass the sequenze where I want to set StrName from the `EditText`.

Comment: It crashes with what? Stacktrace, please. What is more, do NOT do string comparison with `==`/`!=`, use `.equals()` -- but remember that `String` also has `.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 7):

Where is it crashing?

I think that is crashing here:

```
Toast.makeText(null, "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You cannot pass a `null` context to makeText.
If you are in an activity pass it `this` otherwise (if you are in a fragment) pass a `getActivity()`

Also, in Java, NEVER use `!=` or `==` with strings but ALWAYS `s1.equals(s2)` (and before it do a null check)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the below code to compare a string

1.

```
if(StrName.Matches(""))
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

2.

```
if(StrName.compareToIgnoreCase(string))
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
if(StrName != null && StrName.length() > 0)
```

Otherwise it may throw NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the edit text contains null first..

```
if(Name.getText() == null || Name.getText().toString().equals(""))
     Toast.makeText(context, "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  if(!StrName.equals("") && StrName.length() > 0){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Name` and `StrName`if they are null. MakeText requires a `Context`, so it may not be `null` either.

Additionaly

```
if(StrName != "")
```

is not doing what you think, so you should use

```
if(StrName.equals(""))
```

but of course this doesn't cause a crash, just wrong behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To compare String use equals() method and instead of null pass cotext in your Toast :-

```
 if(StrName.equals(""))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got My String.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Too many answers here but interesting thing is that you many of them are passing null as context with Toast :D.... Evaluate yourself your answer.